# Debugging free() with Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging, memory-management

I'm getting the following error while trying to run an iOS app I'm developing:

```
appname(6097,0x3e835d98) malloc: *** error for object 0x20104600: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

How can I find out which call to `free()` generated this error? If I add a breakpoint for `malloc_error_break`, the whole stack trace I get is a call to "`malloc_error_break`" which looks like this:

```
libsystem_c.dylib`malloc_error_break:
0x32f20fa8:  push   {r7, lr}                           < Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1
0x32f20faa:  mov    r7, sp
0x32f20fac:  nop    
0x32f20fae:  nop    
0x32f20fb0:  pop    {r7, pc}
0x32f20fb2:  nop
```

If I don't add a breakpoint for `malloc_error_break`, I get a similarly useless stack trace, but this time with just a `__pthread_kill` and an assembler instruction.

Is there anything else I can do to get a better idea about the code that generated this error?

Comment: Did you try memory profiling with Instruments?

Comment: What's that app that uses malloc() and free()? Aren't you using Objective-C?

Comment: @Sulthan, I did try Instruments, but I couldn't find anything useful there either. But maybe I'm not looking in the right place... All I see while debugging Memory Allocations with Instruments are just that - allocations, nothing about this error.

Comment: I think that the information should be present somewhere in Memory allocations but I couldn't find it either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just created a new project called "Test" with the following `main` method:

```
void* data = malloc(100);    
free(data);
free(data);
```

Then I open "Product->Edit Scheme", click on the "Test.app" tab and click on "Diagnostics". Then I select "Enable Guard Malloc".

Now, if I run the application, I get a break on the second `free`.

Comment: Apparently, you can't use Guard Malloc on the device. I'll try in the simulator.